# Search specific string from other HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been making a search functionality for the other HTML page. I am getting  HTML from another page as a string and trying to parse that string to match data of all `p's` and heading tags. When it finds some specific string then it should return that `p` or `heading` with full text. The problem is that I am getting all the `p's` and `headings` and can't be able to iterate each element step by step.

**Here is my jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $.get("file.html", function(html_string)
   {

     var parsed = $('<html/>').append(html_string);


     $.each(parsed, function( i, el ) {
       console.log(parsed.find("p").text());// here it is getting the text of all the p elements. But I need to iterate each p step by step so that I will be able to search my specific keyword
    });

    },'html');
 });
```

**file.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <p>Zain Farooq</p>
    <h3>search</h3>
    <p>Yes Search this</p><!-- When it finds this then it should return this-->
  </body>
</html>
```

I have also used domparser but it is not giving me desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use .[each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
$.each(parsed, function( i, el ) {
   parsed.find("p").each(function(index) {
       console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes.. Working. Thank you